# Xcode Find Text (code search) adding new line when hitting "return" instead of doing the search

Tags: xcode, search, editor, line, break

I just updated to XCode 8.2.1, when I enter some text in the standard find->text->containing project search box, instead of doing the search, it is creating a new line when I hit "return" (the text I entered scrolls up, you can only see a couple pixels of it, but you can tell its there and up arrow gets you back to that line).  I have never seen XCode do this before.  I'm thinking it is some silly setting somewhere or something simple I am missing, but as far as I know I didn't change any settings, and I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.  I have already tried rebooting the mac, and closing/re-opening XCode which did not help.  I searched stackoverflow and google but couldn't find a solution.

For what it's worth, if I'm running a project in debug mode, with debug console window does the same exact thing, if I type "po myVariable" [return] instead of showing me the value of myVariable, it just creates a new line as if it thinks I want to keep entering text instead of submitting the command I already entered.

[image: can't submit search]

[image: it just creates a new line in the search box]

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the new version of XCode is distinguishing between "return" and "enter".  There is a little info about the difference [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47565/return-vs-enter).  If I hold down the function (fn) key while pressing "return" (I guess this is really "enter" at that point) then Xcode searches submit and I can also submit a command in the debugger.  I'm thinking there must be some setting somewhere that says "treat enter and return the same" but I'm not sure?  At least I have a workaround for now.  If anyone else has the same problem, try using function-return instead of just return.

Comment: Glad I saw this answer, It has been such a terrible experience using Xcode. Wish it executed the search without needing to hit another key (return/ fn+return)